# Compiling am335x-boneblack.dts fails

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am trying to compile a dtb for the beagle bone black (BBB) that I can pass from uboot and have all the peripherals configured as I want them. I need to do it this way rather than applying overlays as we are designing a board based on the BBB and we want to have the peripherals configured at boot.

The command I have used to try to compile the dtb is below.
`dtc -I dts -@ -O dtb -o am335x-boneblack.dtb am335x-boneblack.dts`

To get the `-@` option to work I followed the instructions [here](http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone#BeagleBone-Upgradedistro%22device-tree-compiler%22package):

I have tried pulling the device tree source from multiple places and compiling it.

When pulling from `http://git.ti.com/ti-linux-kernel/ti-linux-3-8-y-kernel/trees/master/arch/arm/boot/dts`, I can compile it but once uboot says "Starting kernel ..." there is no further response.

When pulling from `githubdotcom/beagleboard/devicetree-source` I am unable to compile. It is returning a syntax error on the `#include` statements. I have tried to change these to `/include/` but there are includes in a `<foo/bar>` that fail. If I fix those to absolute things inside the include break.

I believe that the build from the TI repo is the correct path to pursue but I have been unable to get the kernel to boot. I have tried adding a `-b 0` option (no binary difference in dtb) and removing the `-@` but the file is significantly smaller (11k to -@ 15k to default that works 29k) and doesn't boot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the yocto kernel I was using wasn't happy with the dtb files that I compiled.

Replacing am335x-boneblack.dtb in the dtbs folder in the latest BBB debian image from http://beagleboard.org/latest-images resulted in the Kernel trying to boot and then panicing! Much better.

I found the source tree here https://github.com/dominicgs/BeagleDancer/tree/master/devicetree and compiled it using the compile method mentioned in my question and the command **dtc -O dtb -o am335x-boneblack.dtb -b 0 -@ am335x-boneblack.dts**. This successfully booted the BBB so that I could login.